# What are the effects/filters being used in these pictures?

Tags: post-processing, effect

What are the special effects and filters that applies in these pictures:

http://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/933920_650214808328552_285093563_n.jpg

http://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/970894_650237511659615_373924381_n.jpg

Comment: Please [read this post](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions) on asking "what's this effect" questions in a way which will get helpful answers (and upvotes!) and edit this question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: I hope you are only asking this because you want to know what *not* to do.  Those photos are horrible.

Answer (score 3):

It is desaturated, and then shifted to a yellow/black duotone.  It is also badly over exposed to cause a loss of detail on the bright end (can be emulated with curves or brightness).  Noise also appears to have been added.

Answer (score 1):

That processing is pretty terrible.

- In colour balance, remove almost all blue from the low or mid-tones.
- In curves, make a curve that looks a bit like [this](http://laurashoe.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/ps-tat-curves1.jpg).
- Might want to bump up the contrast and brightness a bit.
- In curves, switch to the blue channel.  Play around a bit, but something like [this](https://tutorial9.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2008/06/curves.gif) or [this](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/background-9-letterpress-embossed-text-effect-tutorial-photoshop.jpg) may work (for blue channel only).
- Add noise.
- It probably helps if your photo is grossly overexposed to begin with or you are shooting into the sun or something.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the yellow toning and noise, the main thing I see is no mid-tones.  So they have increased the contrast, and it looks like they've raised the black point up a bit, as there don't seem to be any true blacks in the image (part of that may be due to the noise), which gives it a washed out effect.

So you could use the contrast slider, or you could raise overall exposure, lower shadows, raise highlights and raise the blacks a bit.  Could also try lowering clarity if using Lightroom/Photoshop.